# Rails: Create multiple series chart that contains values by date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, charts

I have an app that has table with values like e.g. weight, height and chest values. I want to place them in multiple series chart that will show value of every record by date for specific user. I am using chartkick gem, but I haven't found an example that would help me. I'm not even sure that it's possible with this gem. If there is any way to do this (I don't have to use Chartkick) I will be grateful.

Thanks!

Update:
Table I'm going to use

```
create_table "body_infos", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.float "height"
    t.float "weight"
    t.float "chest"
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_body_infos_on_user_id"
  end
```

Comment: It is possible. Can you paste your table from schema file?

Comment: @RolandasBarysas I've added schema to the post